# How to export SSIS (SQL Server Integration System) packages to third party data source

Tags: ssis

I want to export SSIS packages into a HANA databse. Please guide me through the exact steps to achieve this.

Comment: What benefit would you derive from exporting an SSIS package into HANA?

Answer (score 1):

I found an article about that, the version is to HANA 4.1.

> To move data from SQL Server to HANA, you can use [SAP BODS](http://scn.sap.com/community/data-services/blog/2013/01/24/data-services-workbench-part-1) in version
>   4.1 SP1 brings improved migrate with an assistant.
>
> Other methods such as:   Sybase replication server.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My requirement is to use SSIS instead BODS.